# How to divide long text in td in to 3 lines, which has specific width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to divide specific td into 3 lines, and set specific width for that particular column, so if it is overflow 3 lines, putting 3 dots "...".
Overall I need td with following criteria:

1. Width 200px
2. Can Take 3 Lines
3. If overflowing the sizes above putting "..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may used line clamp:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
    width: 100px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell ACell ACell ACell ACell ACell ACell ACell ACell All ACell ACell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it helped me, but isnt work with material design, could please look to my code and help https://jsfiddle.net/jnb75vp8/1/

Comment: @NurdauletShamilov sure let me check.

Comment: As you are using material Table. You need to override below material class:

`.mdc-data-table__table {
 white-space: inherit; 
}`

Comment: it was also one step ahead but it looks weird now, how can i center text vertically and have some padding from bottom and top, i tried to use padding but it is showing hided text, thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

Adding this css will do the job

```
{
    width:80%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
}
```

- must have a width, max-width or flex-basis
- must have white-space: nowrap
- must have overflow with value other than visible
- must be display: block or inline-block (or the functional equivalent, such as  a flex item).

```css
p {
    width:80%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed dui felis. Vivamus vitae pharetra nisl, eget fringilla elit. Ut nec est sapien. Aliquam dignissim velit sed nunc imperdiet cursus. Proin arcu diam, tempus ac vehicula a, dictum quis nibh. Maecenas vitae quam ac mi venenatis vulputate. Suspendisse fermentum suscipit eros, ac ultricies leo sagittis quis. Nunc sollicitudin lorem eget eros eleifend facilisis. Quisque bibendum sem at bibendum suscipit. Nam id tellus mi. Mauris vestibulum, eros ac ultrices lacinia, justo est faucibus ipsum, sed sollicitudin sapien odio sed est. In massa ipsum, bibendum quis lorem et, volutpat ultricies nisi. Maecenas scelerisque sodales ipsum a hendreritLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sed dui felis. Vivamus vitae pharetra nisl, eget fringilla elit. Ut nec est sapien. Aliquam dignissim velit sed nunc imperdiet cursus. Proin arcu diam, tempus ac vehicula a, dictum quis nibh. Maecenas vitae quam ac mi venenatis vulputate. Suspendisse fermentum suscipit eros, ac ultricies leo sagittis quis. Nunc sollicitudin lorem eget eros eleifend facilisis. Quisque bibendum sem at bibendum suscipit. Nam id tellus mi. Mauris vestibulum, eros ac ultrices lacinia, justo est faucibus ipsum, sed sollicitudin sapien odio sed est. In massa ipsum, bibendum quis lorem et, volutpat ultricies nisi. Maecenas scelerisque sodales ipsum a hendrerit.</p>
```